# On click in adapter class (ListView)

Tags: java, android, listview

I need some help with my on click in my adapter class.
This is the code that I want to run when an item is clicked.  `connectOrDisconnectUser()`

```
 private void connectOrDisconnectUser(final int position) {


        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                RelationshipRemoved.this);
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to un tag " + usersInfo.get(position).get(
                RelationshipRemoved.likedOne))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",

                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            //do something

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int randomvar) {
                                Log.d("OkHttpRemove", "getting removing!");
                                String username = (globalInt);
                                String UT = usersInfo.get(position).get(
                                        RelationshipRemoved.likedOne);
                                String type = "remove";
                                BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(getApplicationContext());
                                backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, UT);
                                startActivity(new Intent(RelationshipRemoved.this, MainActivity.class));
                                Toast.makeText(context, "UnTagged!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

The file that holds the adapter is called AdapterClass and the class that uses the adapter class is Called RelationshipRemoved. When I try to write this code. I get an error on  `RelationshipRemoved.this` on this line  `RelationshipRemoved.this);`, `startActivity` and  `RelationshipRemoved.this` on this line    `startActivity(new Intent(RelationshipRemoved.this, MainActivity.class));`

What's wrong?

Comment: so you are trying to create an AlertDialog from within an Adapter class? What error are you getting?

Comment: Can you show the logcat, what is the error exactly ?

Comment: I think i got your point, actually in adapter **RelationshipRemoved.this** won't work. because the instance of activity is not in adapter. Take **Context as parameter** in adapter and replace **RelationshipRemoved.this** with that **context object**. That's it !!

Comment: Mayank, please be more specific.

Comment: I did that but i still get an error

Comment: Nvm i got it....

Comment: I still get an error over startActivity, and getApplicationContext()

Comment: fixed it.......

Comment: One error tho on the alert biulder,                                        `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference`